# Permission Denied: Initializing repo for building Android source

Tags: android, android-source

Linux and programming noob here...

I'm following the instructions @ http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html
I run into trouble when I run the following line:

```
curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo > ~/bin/repo
```

I get:

```
bash: /home/dev/bin/repo: Permission denied
```

And yes I've tried to sudo it.

Thank you! :)

==================================================================================
EDIT:

I downloaded the script manually in a browser, popped-it into the home/dev/bin/ directory, and I am still unable to progress. Here is what my terminal window is giving me:

```
dev@Android-Dev:~$ sudo chmod a+x ~/bin/repo

[sudo] password for dev: 

dev@Android-Dev:~$ cd /home/dev/bin/

dev@Android-Dev:~/bin$ sudo mkdir wip

dev@Android-Dev:~/bin$ cd wip

dev@Android-Dev:~/bin/wip$ repo init -u **<This is where the URL goes>**

fatal: cannot make .repo directory: Permission denied

dev@Android-Dev:~/bin/wip$ sudo repo init -u **<This is where the URL goes>**

sudo: repo: command not found

dev@Android-Dev:~/bin/wip$ cd bin

bash: cd: bin: No such file or directory

dev@Android-Dev:~/bin/wip$ cd ..

dev@Android-Dev:~/bin$ sudo repo init -u **<This is where the URL goes>**

sudo: repo: command not found
```

Comment: Does /home/dev/bin exist? If so, is there a file called repo in it already?

Comment: Yes and Yes. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: @Shobi - why are you doing everything with `sudo`? Do a `sudo rm -rf ~/bin/repo` to delete the directory. Then run all the commands again *without* sudo. Also, post the results of `ls -al ~/bin`. Finally, what platform are you on?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. changing the ownership helped me. When I try to curl `https..://myrepo...u...r...l../repo > ./repo` into my `/opt/android dir` it gives me this error. 
I do `sudo chown -R shraddha /opt/android` that works

Answer (score 1):

In CYGWIN you can do below.

1. edit `.bash_profile` and uncomment these fields.  (any text editor will do)

```
# Set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
# if [ -d "${HOME}/bin" ] ; then
#   PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
# fi
```

2. Restart CYGWIN.

Under BASH, enter:

```
$ export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
```

Or add as follows to your `.bashrc` file:

```
$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:~/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

If you are using CSH / TCSH, enter:

```
$ echo 'set PATH = ($PATH ~/bin /scripts/admin)' >> ~/.cshrc
```

To display path settings, enter:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're behind a proxy? Try to download repo tool manually (just put this link into your browser). (I guess that maybe this resource can be prohibited for you). And then put it into this folder and assign permissions to it. I do not see any wrong steps in what you've described so far.

Comment: Thank you Yury. I downloaded the script through the browser, popped it into the directory and I'm still having problems. I am not behind a proxy. I think I'm making some kind of a noob mistake ...

Comment: what kind of problems do you have now?

Comment: It seems like your user does not have rights to modify file system. Check this.

Comment: I saw it yesterday. Why do you create folder (mkdir) using sudo? According to this string I can conclude that you do not have write and execute permissions to your home directory.

Comment: Ok thank you. I tried mkdir without sudo and you're right, I still get permission denied. This seems unusual to me, that I don't have permissions to write and execute to my home dir. I'm new to Linux, what went wrong here, and what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: I do not know. By default you should have all permissions to your home directory. Maybe you've done something before?

Comment: This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.04 x64, on a newly formatted HDD. The only things I did before starting to work on Android Source was to check for updates.

Comment: This is almost unreal. I am not a professional in Ubuntu, but I've never faced with such type of problems. Maybe, you've enabled encryption of your home directory and this causes this type of problems. However, you can try command chmod for your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
wget http://git-repo.googlecode.com/files/repo-1.14

After that,
you can see the repo-1.14, and you can mv it to anywhere or change the name,such as :
sudo mv repo-1.14 ~/bin/repo

Answer (score 0):

The repo file is not executable. Run `chmod a+x ~/bin/repo` to turn it into an executable file and this should fix your problem.